# Failed to setup marker on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Hi i am trying to implement marker on Google maps but it is not working , I am pasting my script mere
Please tell me where i am doing it wrong. thank you

```
    <script>
    var map;
    function initialize() {

        var Longitude = document.getElementById('Longitude').value;
        var Lattitude = document.getElementById('Lattitude').value;
        console.log(Longitude + '' + Lattitude);
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var isDraggable = $(document).width() < 1000 == false;
        var map_options = {

            center: new google.maps.LatLng(Lattitude, Longitude),
            zoom: 15,
            draggable: isDraggable,

            scrollwheel: false,
            //    navigationControl: false,
            //mapTypeControl: false,
            //scaleControl: false,


            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Longitude, Lattitude);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!',
            animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,

        });
        marker.setMap(map)

    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: try with calling initialize() directly in case your event not getting fired.. also you may need to set css height for 'map_canvas' element. bkz ur map might get rendered but not visible  due to zero height. Also map requires valid lat/lng combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you swapped longitude/lattitude.  LatLng() first asks for lattitude (There is probably a marker at some completely different part of the globe, on your map).
Just change that part of your code to this:

```
...
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(Lattitude, Longitude);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!',
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
//marker.setMap(map)
...
```

You don't need marker.setMap(map).  That is already done with map: map,

Answer (score 0):

I got your code working (although I faked the lat and long instead of using textboxes).

I can offer a couple of bits of advice:

```
* Make sure the google maps script and jQuery scripts are loaded before your code
* Ensure your textboxes are populated before the domready event fires
* When loading the page, press F12 and refresh.  Check the console that pops up for errors
```